# In $\Delta ABC,\cos A+\sin A-\frac{2}{\cos B+\sin B}=0,$then prove that $\frac{a+b}{c}=\sqrt2$

Tags: trigonometry

In $\Delta ABC,\cos A+\sin A-\frac{2}{\cos B+\sin B}=0,$then prove that $\frac{a+b}{c}=\sqrt2$

---

$\cos A+\sin A-\frac{2}{\cos B+\sin B}=0$
$\cos A+\sin A=\frac{2}{\cos B+\sin B}$
$\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B+\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B=2$
$\cos(A-B)+\sin(A+B)=2$
We need to find the value of $\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac{\sin A+\sin B}{\sin C}$...by sine rule
$\frac{\sin A+\sin B}{\sin C}=\frac{2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})}{2\sin\frac{C}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}}=\frac{\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})}{\sin\frac{C}{2}}$
I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $\cos(A-B) \leq 1, \sin(A+B) \leq 1 \Rightarrow \cos(A-B) = 1 = \sin(A+B) \Rightarrow A+B = \pi/2, A = B$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This makes no sense...if I accept your conclusion that $A + B = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $A = B$, then we have $A = B = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and thus $C = \frac{\pi}{2}$ therefore, finally, that $\frac{A+B}{C} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 1 \neq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Jared The question said $\frac{a+b}c$ not $\frac{A+B}C$.  Presumably this is the usual convention that capitals denote angles and lowercase denotes sides.

Comment: @David OK, that's a new one on me--I've never heard of such a convention--in fact I generally thought lower case would have meant angles...

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\cos(A-45^\circ)=(\cos A)\frac1{\sqrt2}+(\sin A)\frac1{\sqrt2}\ .$$
So some simple algebra turns your equation into
$$\cos(A-45^\circ)\cos(B-45^\circ)=1\ .$$
Now cos of anything is between $1$ and $-1$, so the only possibilities are
$$\cos(A-45^\circ)=\cos(B-45^\circ)=1$$
and
$$\cos(A-45^\circ)=\cos(B-45^\circ)=-1\ .$$
See if you can explain why the second is impossible in a triangle; then find angles $A,B$ from the first equation.  Then draw the triangle and solve the problem!